# How to generate specific combination of numbers in Python

Tags: python, list, numbers

what I'm trying to do is a function for which you give a number and it lists every string of that length that contain numbers in ascending order with the conditions that I cannot have more than 4 time the same number and my number have to be consecutive. If possible, I would like not to list numbers that are anacycle of those already listed.

For example:
fct(5) gives me
"11112
11122
11123
11223 (11222 is omitted)
11233
11234
12223
12234
12345"

Do you think it is better to do this with regex and generate every combination or to increment the numbers in a list while I browse my initial list and modify it ?

Are other languages better to do something like this ?

EDIT : Sorry I think it wasn't enough clear.
I tried at beginning to do something like :

```
ls = list("1111222233334")
i = -1
while ls[0] == "1":
    print("".join(ls))
    if int(ls[i]) == int(ls[i-1]) and int(ls[i]) < 9:
        ls[i] = str(int(ls[i])+1)
    else:
        i -= 1
```

Of course this doesn't work and I think there is too much condition if I go this way, this is why I ask if there is something already done in Python that can list every ascending number of specific length.
We cannot go over 9 so this function does anything if called with 37.

By anacycle I mean something that gives something else if read starting by the end (like "roma" and "amor").

Is it better to generate a list of every number of that length and then delete all those that do not correspond, + delete those that are equivalent to those that are already in ?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at trying to generate the numbers?

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that *regex* may be a good tool for this job? Also, please show what  you have tried.

Comment: What is an "anacycle"? Why is `11222` omitted from your example list? What about `12222` and `112334`? What if the specified number is greater than `9` so there are not enough digits for a strictly increasing run of decimal digits? Your problem specification is not clear enough.

Comment: I edited my message ; I thought that you could find patterns like this one with regex ; it's just a number of 1 followed by a number of 2...

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to do this :

```
def handlisting(n):
    L = [str(i) for i in range (int("1"*n), int(12345679 * (10**(n-8))) + 1)]
reg = "1{1,4}(2{1,4}(3{1,4}(4{1,4}(5{1,4}(6{1,4}(7{1,4}(8{1,4}(9{1,4})?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?\Z"
return list(filter(re.compile(reg).match, L))
```

I think that I can do better because this one is pretty slow, and it doesn't delete those that are the same than other if read starting by the end (it will return "112234" and "123344", or "11112" and "12222")

EDIT : It goes a little faster with a condition like this :

```
L = [str(i) for i in range (int("1"*n), int(12345679 * (10**(n-8))) + 1) if \
    i%10 >= (i//10)%10 and i%100 >= (i//10)%100 and i%1000 >= (i//10)%1000 and i%10000 >= (i//10)%10000]
```